# Vue accessing data from method

Tags: vue.js

I have the following code:

```js
export default {
  name: "App",

  data() {
    return {
      ipAddress: "",
      client: "8.8.8.8",
      peer: "",
    };
  },

  components: {
    VsaList,
    VsaItem,
    VsaHeading,
    VsaContent,
  },

  methods: {
    traceRoute() {
      var pl = this;

      console.log("I should trace ip address:", this.ipAddress);
      var hostname = { ipAddr: this.ipAddress };

      axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:3001/trace",
        data: hostname,
        headers: { "content-type": "text/plain" },
      })
        .then((result) => {
          pl.client = "9.9.9.9";
          console.log(result.data.ipAddr);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
};
```

The `client` variable is set to '8.8.8.8' in the `data()` definition, but when I attempt to update the variable later with `pl.client = "9.9.9.9"` it does not actually change the variable within the HTML.

Is there anything else that needs to be done to make this variable reactive?

Here is the HTML:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="app" class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 py-5">
          <h1>Traceroute</h1>

          <form v-on:submit.prevent="traceRoute">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input
                v-model="ipAddress"
                type="text"
                id="website-input"
                placeholder="Enter an IP Address"
                class="form-control"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button class="btn btn-primary">Trace</button>
            </div>
          </form>

          <vsa-list>
            <vsa-item>
              <vsa-heading> {{ client }} </vsa-heading>

              <vsa-content> {{ peer }} </vsa-content>
            </vsa-item>
          </vsa-list>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Did you look at Vue dev tools how this variable changes?

Comment: How do you call that method?

Comment: Can you add the html used to render the client variable?

Comment: does this statement `console.log("I should trace ip address:", this.ipAddress);` give an output?

Comment: Yep the console.log gives the expected output

Comment: Does `console.log(result.data.ipAddr);` work? I mean your request is ok?

Comment: Does your Promise do it successfully? Or just goes to Catch?

Comment: If you are sure ur request is being executed properly you can try somethig like this
pl.$set(pl, 'client', "9.9.9.9").

https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is the problem

```
pl.client = "9.9.9.9";
```

The update you're doing is not reactive, it will not trigger an re-render of your value in the html.

When you're updating single object values you need to use Vue.set

```
this.$set(this.pl, 'client', "9.9.9.9" }
```

If you need to update more than a property at once, you could use Object.assign :
For the sake of the example, let's imagine you the client is a object containing 3 properties, and you want to update some of them, you recreate the object with it current properties, and update the one to be updated

```
 this.state.client = Object.assign({}, this.client, updatedObject)
```

Let me know if it has worked, in the meantime i could advice you to read more about reactivity in vuejs, it will save you some time once in a while :)

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and initially got an error regarding pl being declared but never used on build, so I adjusted it to this.$set(pl, "client", "9.9.9.9"} and getting the same results where the variable in html is not updated.

Comment: why do you need do declare pl = this ?  couldn't just do this.client = myNewValue ?
As far as i see, your client property in data isn't nested or anything.

Comment: I did initially try this.client = newValue and that did not work either, added the pl = this based on something else I had seen in a post but don't think it is necessary here

Comment: could you log the result of your promise,  maybe it goes to the error? For debugger add a watcher and log the value of client and let me see please. Show me as well the template of vsa heading please

Comment: So after playing around a little more, I noticed that if I just put the html variable {{ client }} in an header tag, it updates just fine. It seems that when trying to update the variable within the <vsa-content> tag is where the problem lies.

Comment: I wanted to see the template, maybe the slot isn't correct or there anything else bugging, but good for you it work dude :)

Comment: Thanks for your help on this!